# Can a progressive webapp access secure storage of android/IOS device?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, progressive-web-apps

I am exploring progressive webapps. I understand that PWAs are able to access local storage on the device.
I wanted to know if it possible for it to access secure storage of the device?(for say storing private key etc.)

Comment: What do you consider to be the secure storage of a device?

Comment: @blackapps:Android provides a specialized storage for saving cryptographic materials like privet keys. I want to know if there is any way to save crypto material using PWA.

Comment: `secure storage` or `specialized storage`. What would be the storage location?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339870/android-secure-storage